# How to use outfit?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

How to use `outfit` in a sentence?

Like for example:

> I need to buy a sports outfit

is correct?

If I want to make it plural,

> I need to buy some sports outfits

can be used?

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary? I'm not sure why you think it may be incorrect.

Comment: Because all the examples in the dictionary, had no article before, like for example "This outfit is perfect"

Comment: Then you need to check more than one dictionary, or maybe look it up on the internet, because I found multiple dictionaries that give examples or explain that *outfit* is a countable noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *outfit* is a set containing one or more items of clothes that is for a single person to wear.  An outfit can have 1 item, such as a dress, or multiple items, such as shoulder pads, helmet, etc.  Even if it has multiple items, we care about the set of items as a single unit, so we use the singular unless we mean multiple sets.

Put a simpler way: You'd buy multiple outfit*s* if you had multiple people each needing to wear them.  If just one person, then say *outfit*.

Comment: Well, you could have multiple outfits for one person. Like you could say "I have 3 outfits: this one is for Monday, this one for Tuesday, and this one for Wednesday". But basically, yes, agree.